# Node.js async :success message after upload in for loop

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

Here is my function to upload some data to aws s3 in a loop.

```
    for (var i=0;i<crop_sizes.length;i++){
                uploadToS3(crop_sizes[i]);
            }

function uploadToS3(crops){

   s3.upload(crops,function(err,success){
     if(!err){
       console.log('uploaded');
     }
})

}
```

Its works fine but i want to show a success message after all uploads so how can i achive it `async` libray.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`async.each`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each) if you want to stick with this library.

```
each(crop_sizes, s3.upload.bind(s3), function(err) {
  if(err) { 
    console.error(err)
  } else {
    console.log('success')
  }
})
```

Comment: what is `bind(s3)`  i can't understand it

Comment: @Jabaa https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: But how is it applicable in my case??

Comment: Pretty straight forward: it creates a funciton that calls `s3.upload` withing `s3` context. I do recommend  you to read some docs, really.

Comment: Well i have to  pass some arguments to `upload`

Comment: @Jabaa Then replace it with whatever function you need that takes crops and callback and make sure it calls the callback when done.

Answer (score 0):

```
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < crop_sizes.length; i++) {
    promises.push(uploadToS3(crop_sizes[i]));
}
function uploadToS3(crops) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.upload(crops, function (err, success) {
            if (err) {
                return reject();
            }
            resolve();
        })
    });
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
    console.log('success');
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: The question was about `async` library.